# Como funciona o "while / do" em Scala 3?

Tags: loop, scala, scala-3

Lendo as mudanças previstas para o Scala 3, descobri que o [do-while foi descontinuado](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/do-while.html).
Entendo que um *loop* *do-while* sempre pode ser reescrito como um `while`. Dito isso, os exemplos do artigo com um `while` seguido de `do` são um pouco difíceis de entender.

```
while
   i += 1
   f(i) == 0
do ()
```

E um outro exemplo:

```
while
   val x: Int = iterator.next
   x >= 0
do print(".")
```

Como essa construção funciona? Me parece que a condição fica no último comando no corpo do `while`, e que o `do` só irá ser executado se essa condição for verdadeira. Meu entendimento está correto?

Comment: Parte da minha iniciativa para trazer mais perguntas para a comunidade.